# Java GUI Game: Help using Jframes

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

Ive been playing around with some code to teach myself JFrames. I've got myself in a complete mess with coding this game. What i'm trying to achieve is to take the current code with is just sat in a jframe (with has no support for re-sizing) and place it in a better constructed window. with 3 panels one for the game buttons to the left one to the right for status labels and one at the button also for labels.

At the moment the class extends Jframe but not makeFrame method has been introduced which I've been trying to do. The following code is initialized in the constructor. The corresponding fields are there, i haven't included them but they all compile.

```
    buttons = new JButton[boardsize][boardsize];
    mineBoard = new int[9][9];
    setSize(boardsize * gridsize + 60, boardsize * gridsize + 180);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);


    getContentPane().add(namelabel);
    getContentPane().add(scorelabel);
    getContentPane().add(gamesPlayed);


    // LABEL POSITIONING ON BOARD
    scorelabel.setBounds(30, 30 + gridsize * boardsize, 130, 30);
    namelabel.setBounds(40, 40 + gridsize * boardsize, 130, 30);
    gamesPlayed.setBounds(60, 60 + gridsize * boardsize, 130, 30);


    for (int a = 0; a < boardsize; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < boardsize; b++) {
            buttons[a][b] = new JButton("");
            getContentPane().add(buttons[a][b]);
            buttons[a][b].setBounds(30 + gridsize * a, 30 + gridsize * b, gridsize, gridsize);
            buttons[a][b].addMouseListener(new MouseListener(a, b));
            //buttons[a][b].setIcon( new ImageIcon( "images/rock.jpg" ) );

            setx(a);
            sety(b);
            settried(false);
            setmine(false);
        }
    }

    assignmines();
    setVisible(true);
    updateGamesPlayed();
    UpdateName();
    updatescore();
```

If anyone can help in any way as to how i can achieve the aim with a makeFrame() method that would be great.

Comment: Your first problem is `getContentPane().setLayout(null);`. Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  2) Also, asking a question would be useful..

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep these both in mind and think of a better way to ask.